# Play Audio File only when modals open

Tags: javascript, html

I have a trigger button which opens a modal, when someone clicks on it and at the same time, it will play an audio file. So far so good.

Where I'm struggling is, how to play the audio file only when the modal is getting opened? At the moment it plays the sound every time, so if someone opens it and if someone close it. So every time the trigger `.pop-icon` is clicked.

JS:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var e = document.createElement("audio");
    (e.src = "https://intern.globallabs.de/message.mp3"),
        (e.volume = 0.5),
        (e.autoPlay = !1),
        (e.preLoad = !0),
        $(".pop-icon").click(function () {
            e.play();
        });
});
```

HTML Trigger:

```
<div class="pop-icon">...</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I understand...
In this case, you could use an attribute to save the modals state:

```js
// Some shorthands
const $ = document;
$.get = $.getElementById;
const log = console.log;
const warn = console.warn;
const error = console.error;

const trigger = $.get('trigger');

trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (trigger.getAttribute('data-is-open') == 'false') {
    trigger.setAttribute('data-is-open', 'true');
    $.get('modal').style.display = 'block';
    trigger.innerHTML = 'close';
    playSound('https://intern.globallabs.de/message.mp3');
  } else {
    $.get('modal').style.display = 'none';
    trigger.innerHTML = 'reopen';
    trigger.setAttribute('data-is-open', 'false');
  }
});

function playSound(url) {
  const audio = document.createElement('audio');
  audio.src = url;
  // Your audio settings
  audio.play();
}
```

```css
#modalContainer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 1rem;
  right: 1rem;
}

#modal {
  display: none;
  width: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 1000;
}

#trigger {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="modalContainer">
      <div id="modal">
        This is the Modal
      </div>
      <button id="trigger" data-is-open="false">open</button>
     </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sir. You made my day - Even better. You made my weekend. Thx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```js
// Some shorthands
const $ = document;
$.get = $.getElementById;
const log = console.log;
const warn = console.warn;
const error = console.error;

$.body.addEventListener('click', function() {
  $.get('trigger').addEventListener('click', function() {
    $.get('overlay').style.display = 'block';
    $.get('modal').style.display = 'block';
    playSound('https://intern.globallabs.de/message.mp3');
  });
});

function playSound(url) {
  const audio = document.createElement('audio');
  audio.src = url;
  // Your audio settings
  audio.play();
}
```

```css
#overlay {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #0008;
  z-index: 50;
}

#modal {
  display: none;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 2rem auto;
  padding: .5rem;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 4px;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    Click the button to <button id="trigger">open</button> the Modal and play the sound.
    <div id="overlay"></div>
    <div id="modal">
      This is the Modal
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not  really. You can see it here: http://peymanwebsite.webflow.io. The yellow toggle bottom right. If it's open the modal is opening and the sound comes. But when i close it, the sound comes again. It should only came when open.